# Promtail/Grafana: Can not have at the same time labels and timestamp

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I'm working on Promtail configuration in order to retrieve some information from logs through Loki on Grafana.
Each line contains the timestamp at the beginning, and after the cpu usage.

The regex allows to get both.

I can set properly the timestamp with the source `time` and the format. It works.

But if I add the `labels` section, Grafana will not display any logs. Otherwise, I have my label inside Grafana to filter on.

In the opposite, if I comment the timestamp and not the labels, I have all my logs on Grafana but with the timestamp on ingestion, not the one from the log line...

Do you know what did I miss here? It's pretty annoying to have either the correct timestamp or the labels...

Regards

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: jobname
      __path__: /var/log/*/*log
  pipeline_stages:
    - regex:
        expression: "^(?P<time>[\\d\\-T:.]+Z)\\s.*cpu_usage=(?P<cpu_usage>([\\d.]+))"
    - timestamp:
        source: time
        format: RFC3339Nano
        location: "Europe/Paris"
        action_on_failure: fudge
    # If I comment this part, logs appears on Grafana
    - labels:
        time:
        cpu_usage:
```